# DataGrip-Presto JDBC: Timezone displays incurrect even after setting -Duser.timezone=+0800

Tags: datagrip

[Datagrip post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001787960-Presto-JDBC-Timezone-displays-incurrect-even-after-setting-Duser-timezone-0800)

---

Current time is `2018-11-27 14:52:11` timezone=+0800

But

`select now()` is `2018-11-27 06:52:11` (Wrong)

```
-- result: 2018-11-27 00:00:07, 2018-11-27 06:52:37 (Wrong)
select 
    min(sale_time), 
    max(sale_time) 
from sales 
where sale_time > current_date and sale_time <= now()
```

After setting VM options to `-Duser.timezone=+0800`

`select now()` is `2018-11-27 06:52:11` (Wrong)

```
-- result: 2018-11-27 00:00:07, 2018-11-27 14:52:57 (Right)
select 
    min(sale_time), 
    max(sale_time) 
from sales 
where sale_time > current_date and sale_time <= now()
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there is no possibility to display date in other time zone than UTC. There is an feature request to implement custom data displaying in DataGrip: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6667